# Sending hex characters over a socket

Tags: perl, sockets

I am trying to send a hex character to a socket to indicate a new message.  This code works:

```
  $socket->send("\x{0B}");
  $socket->send($contents);
  $socket->send("\x{1C}");
  $socket->send("\x{0D}");
```

However, since this happens in a loop, I need variable hex characters, and I have not figure out how to get it to work.  This is what I have tried.

```
my $start_char = get(); # returns, for example 0B
my $end_char = get(); # 1C
my $end_seg = get(); #0D

$socket->send("\x{$start_char}");
$socket->send($contents);
$socket->send("\x{$end_char}");
$socket->send("\x{$end_seg}");
```

I can verify that the variables returned by the function are correct on the perl side, but the server does not accept them as valid characters.  Any input regarding how to do this?

Comment: There's no such thing as a *hex character*, nor any requirement to use a hex representation of a character to `send`.

Comment: @mob, I'd say there are 16 hex characters, but I agree that he simply meant "character" when he said "hex character".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `...send( chr($start_char) );`, etc. (guessing that `get()` is actually returning integers).
If it really gives you strings like "0B", then `...send( chr(hex($start_chr)) );`

Answer (score 2):

If you have a small amount of data, ysth's answer makes sense.

If you have a larger amount of data, you may want to look at `pack`.

`pack ("H*", "0B")` and `pack ("C*", 0x0B)` both give `"\x0B"`.